# Finding an efficient way to count the number of overlaps between interval sets in two tables?

Tags: r, data.table

*Note: I am using an example dataset from a previous post for convenience purposes.*

Suppose that there are two data sets, `ref` and `map`. They are:

```
ref <- data.table(space=rep('nI',3),t1=c(100,300,500),t2=c(150,400,600),id=letters[1:3])

map <- data.table(space=rep('nI',241),t1=seq(0,1200,by=5),t2=seq(5,1205,by=5),res=rnorm(241))
```

they look like:

```
> ref
   space t1  t2   id
1:    nI 100 150  a
2:    nI 300 400  b
3:    nI 500 600  c

> map
   space   t1   t2        res
1:    nI    0    5 -0.7082922
2:    nI    5   10  1.8251041
3:    nI   10   15  0.2076552
4:    nI   15   20  0.8047347
5:    nI   20   25  2.3388920
---                           
237:    nI 1180 1185  1.0229284
238:    nI 1185 1190 -0.3657815
239:    nI 1190 1195  0.3013489
240:    nI 1195 1200  1.2947271
241:    nI 1200 1205 -1.5050221
```

Now, it has come to my attention that in the data.table package that is still under development, the function `foverlaps` will fill in intervals in `ref` with the corresponding rows in `map`.

```
setkey(ref,space,t1,t2)

foverlaps(map,ref,type="within",nomatch=0L)
```

which gives:

```
   space t1  t2  id i.t1 i.t2         res
1:    nI 100 150  a  100  105 -0.85202726
2:    nI 100 150  a  105  110  0.79748876
3:    nI 100 150  a  110  115  1.49894097
4:    nI 100 150  a  115  120  0.47719957
5:    nI 100 150  a  120  125 -0.95767896
6:    nI 100 150  a  125  130 -0.51054673
7:    nI 100 150  a  130  135 -0.08478700
8:    nI 100 150  a  135  140 -0.69526566
9:    nI 100 150  a  140  145  2.14917623
10:    nI 100 150  a  145  150 -0.05348163
11:    nI 300 400  b  300  305  0.28834548
12:    nI 300 400  b  305  310  0.32449616
13:    nI 300 400  b  310  315  1.16107248
14:    nI 300 400  b  315  320  1.08550676
15:    nI 300 400  b  320  325  0.84640788
16:    nI 300 400  b  325  330 -2.15485447
17:    nI 300 400  b  330  335  1.59115714
18:    nI 300 400  b  335  340 -0.57588128
19:    nI 300 400  b  340  345  0.23957563
20:    nI 300 400  b  345  350 -0.60824259
21:    nI 300 400  b  350  355 -0.84828189
22:    nI 300 400  b  355  360 -0.43528701
23:    nI 300 400  b  360  365 -0.80026281
24:    nI 300 400  b  365  370 -0.62914234
25:    nI 300 400  b  370  375 -0.83485164
26:    nI 300 400  b  375  380  1.46922713
27:    nI 300 400  b  380  385 -0.53965310
28:    nI 300 400  b  385  390  0.98728765
29:    nI 300 400  b  390  395 -0.66328893
30:    nI 300 400  b  395  400 -0.08182384
31:    nI 500 600  c  500  505  0.72566100
32:    nI 500 600  c  505  510  2.27878366
33:    nI 500 600  c  510  515  0.72974139
34:    nI 500 600  c  515  520 -0.35358019
35:    nI 500 600  c  520  525 -1.20697646
36:    nI 500 600  c  525  530 -0.01719057
37:    nI 500 600  c  530  535  0.06686472
38:    nI 500 600  c  535  540 -0.40866088
39:    nI 500 600  c  540  545 -1.02697573
40:    nI 500 600  c  545  550  2.19822065
41:    nI 500 600  c  550  555  0.57075648
42:    nI 500 600  c  555  560 -0.52009726
43:    nI 500 600  c  560  565 -1.82999177
44:    nI 500 600  c  565  570  2.53776578
45:    nI 500 600  c  570  575  0.85626293
46:    nI 500 600  c  575  580 -0.34245708
47:    nI 500 600  c  580  585  1.21679869
48:    nI 500 600  c  585  590  1.87587020
49:    nI 500 600  c  590  595 -0.23325264
50:    nI 500 600  c  595  600  0.18845022
space  t1  t2 id i.t1 i.t2         res
```

to run the developement version of data.table 1.9.3, the following code will help you run it:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
dev_mode(on=T)

install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes=FALSE)

dev_mode(on=F)
```

**What I am trying to do instead:**

The above basically lists out all the intervals contained within the time intervals. However, I am trying to just create a new column by `ref` that **counts** the number of rows in `map` that are within the time intervals of `ref`. Hence, the table I would like is:

```
> ref
   space t1  t2  id  count
1:    nI 100 150  a     10
2:    nI 300 400  b     20
3:    nI 500 600  c     20
```

The count for each indicates how many rows of `map` fell in between each time interval of `ref`. While I understand a very basic solution is to just use a sum or count function to count, is there a solution that would create the counts without having to first create the larger filled in dataset? I say this because my real data contains over 300 million observations. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `which=TRUE` argument to get the position of overlaps, and then use to get the *counts* by doing a simple aggregation:

```
ans = foverlaps(map, ref, type="within", nomatch=0L, which=TRUE)[, .N, by=yid]
#    yid  N
# 1:   1 10
# 2:   2 20
# 3:   3 20
```

And then get this back in `ref`. But we should provide a more direct way to accomplish this.

Comment: hi, thanks so much, i have another question i was wondering if you would have an answer to, if my time data is in POSIXct format, the above doesn't seem to work, would you know of any workarounds? thanks!

Comment: Sure, could you post a link to a gist or edit your question with some sample data?

Comment: hi Arun, thanks for the offer to help, I figured out the date part, i essentially converted from numeric and back. However, I was wondering how your code above would work if the map data were to be sorted by the id variable of ref. Is there a way I can add in "by = id" for the counting? thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to convert to numeric and back. If it doesn't work, then it should be a bug that has skipped the tests, and therefore it'd really help to fix it. And I don't follow your second part.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
count <- function(x, y) map[,sum(t1>=x & t2<=y)]
ref[, count:=mapply(x=t1, y=t2, count)]
ref

   space  t1  t2 id count
1:    nI 100 150  a    10
2:    nI 300 400  b    20
3:    nI 500 600  c    20
```

Answer (score 2):

The *Biocondcutor* [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package, developed for genetic data, has the notion of a 'space' (sequence name), coordinates (integer ranges defined as closed intervals of start and end coordinates) within the space, and 'metadata' columns that are associate with each range. So

```
library(GenomicRanges)
ref <- with(ref, GRanges(space, IRanges(t1, t2), id=id))
map <- with(map, GRanges(space, IRanges(t1, t2), res=rnorm(241)))
```

GenomicRanges support many range-based operations, including

```
ref$count <- countOverlaps(ref, map)
```

to accomplish what you are interested in (countOverlaps supports different notions of overlap, so perhaps the default (any overlap between ranges) is not what you're interested in; a 'range' is inclusive of its start and end, but range can easily be shifted or narrowed; both of these might mean that the direct application of `countOverlaps()` is different from what you were expecting.

To process large amounts of data, it's natural to iterate through in chunks (e.g., of 10M rows of the larger data), either by opening a connection to the data source and reading in successive rows, or by making range-based queries of a data base or whatever file format you have.

```
con <- open("my.csv")
while (nrow(map0 <- read.csv(con, nrows=10000000))) {
    map <- with(map0, GRanges(space, IRanges(t1, t2)))
    ref$count <- ref$count + countOverlaps(ref, map)
}
close(con)
```