# Table of all intersections in two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames. Each row of the dataframes has a different number of elements (actually gene names) -- I used `read.csv("file.csv",fill=TRUE)` to read them in, so there some na padding in some of the rows.

Each of the data frames have the same elements, only they've been clustered differently, so they are in different groups. I want to output a table of the intersections from the two dataframes.

So if

```
df1<-data.frame(c("a","b","NA","NA"),c("c","d","e","f"),c("g","h","i","NA" ),c("j","NA","NA","NA"))
df2<-data.frame(c("c","e","i","NA"),c("f","g","h","NA"),c("a","b","d","j" ))
```

then I want to get to something like this:

```
     df1[1,] df1[2,] df1[3,] df1[4,]
df2[1,] 0      2       1      0
df2[2,] 0      1       2      0
df2[3,] 2      1       0      1
```

It seems like it should be something I should be able to do with intersect() and an apply function of some sort. I can't get my head around it though. Using my google-fu the nearest I can find is this :[Finding an efficient way to count the number of overlaps between interval sets in two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048005/finding-an-efficient-way-to-count-the-number-of-overlaps-between-interval-sets-i), but that deals with data tables and is looking at numerical overlaps in line segments as best I can tell, not lists of names.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: It would be better if your code to generate `df1` and `df2` actually worked.

Comment: Edited. Apologies, I wasn't intending it to be code to execute, rather, I was just trying to get the idea of what I was trying to do across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by looping through the rows of each data frame and then calculating the length of the intersection of the rows, omitting missing values:

```
apply(df1, 1, function(i) apply(df2, 1, function(j) length(na.omit(intersect(i, j)))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    2    1    0
# [2,]    0    1    2    0
# [3,]    2    1    0    1
```

Sample data:

```
(df1<-rbind(c("a","b", NA, NA),c("c","d","e","f"),c("g","h","i", NA),c("j", NA, NA, NA)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "a"  "b"  NA   NA  
# [2,] "c"  "d"  "e"  "f" 
# [3,] "g"  "h"  "i"  NA  
# [4,] "j"  NA   NA   NA  
(df2<-rbind(c("c","e","i", NA),c("f","g","h", NA),c("a","b","d","j")))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "c"  "e"  "i"  NA  
# [2,] "f"  "g"  "h"  NA  
# [3,] "a"  "b"  "d"  "j"
```